# CSS - How to rotate this ribbon

Tags: html, css

Hi I have followed the following tutorial to create a ribbon. However I want the ribbon to be facing horizontally so that I can put text in it and use it as a heading. How can I simply re-do this but make it face horizontal?

http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-smooth-ribbon-with-borders

Answer (score 0):

Just put:

```
transform:rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(90deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
```

to your `#ribbon` div.

If you want to rotate it differently:

```
transform:rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
```

Comment: That makes the text within it also rotate then

Comment: Unless I have to rotate the text back

Comment: You can put the text to div in the `#ribbon` and put rotate -90deg to it.